# What happened to the Unity Test Runner options?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine

Take a look at this screenshot (from [this site](http://www.tallior.com/introduction-unity-test-tools/)):

[image]

Now look at a screenshot from my own copy of Unity (Personal).

[image]

As you can see, a lot appears to be missing. Does anybody know why? Is this a Pro-only thing? I can't find any reference to it.

Comment: Which version of the Unity3D editor are you running?

Comment: 5.6.0f3 Personal. No difference in the latest beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot above is an older version of Test Tools. [UnityTestTools](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/unitytesttools/overview) was an open soruce project, deployed as a Package in the Asset Store. You had to import the asset from Asset Store to use this feature up to Unity 5.5. This is a deprecated project and is not supported anymore from Unity 5.6 (valid until Unity 5.5).

The Unity Technologies apparently liked it so they included the Test Tool as an official feature from Unity 5.6, and renamed it [Test Runner](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html). When you create projects you have the Test Runner included by default, which can be accessed from the tab [Window - Test Runner].

A few major changes I've noticed are:

1. `AssertComponent` no longer exists
2. No Scene-Based-Test out of the box as it used to be. Although [Unity Forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/integration-testing-support-in-5-6.460745/) suggests it should be easy to implement such tests yourself with `PlayMode` I feel like there are not enough ducumentation and examples for beginners.

Comment: Aha! What a curious drop in functionality, considering how seriously they take testing in-house. Agreed that the documentation is sorely lacking. It would have been nice, for example, if I hadn't had to figure out by myself how to use a testing framework other than NUnit.

Comment: Those who can't find it on mac. It's (Window->General->TestRunner)